# Java web service : indicating the input type

Tags: java, wsdl

I'm learning coding SOAP web services with pure JAX-WS RI.
This is my service's interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface Hello {

  @WebMethod
  String hi(String msg);
}
```

And this is my implementation :

```
  @Override
  public String hi(String msg) {
    return "hi " + msg;
  }
```

The problem is that the generated WSDL doesn't indicate that the input type of `hi` his String (xsd:string). Instead, it indicates `use=literal` :

```
<soap:body use="literal"/>
```

How can I display the input type `xsd:string` ?

Regards